# jquery to avoid form to be submitted twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this form in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTransaction", "Addons", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "TransForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
}
```

I am using this jQuery code to submit the form, but it is submitting the form twice.

```
(function () {
    var bar = $('.progress-bar');
    var percent = $('.progress-bar');
    $('#TransForm').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function () {
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
            percent.fadeIn();
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
            percent.fadeOut();

            // Get addonID
            var ID = $('#BatchID').val();

            //Resets form
            ClearSelection();

            //update the partial views
            UpdateEvents(ID);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            ReturnStatus("alert-danger", 'data.responseText');
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            ReturnStatus("alert-success", message);
        }
    });

})();
```

This code works fine—it submits, saves and return the right data—it is just doing it twice.

I tried to include `beforeSend: function(e)...`, then `e.preventDefault();`, but it didn't change anything. How I can change it to include `e.preventDefault();` so the form wont send it twice?

Comment: `ajaxForm`  is not a jQuery function and afaik there are different plugins for jQuery adding a `ajaxForm` function, so you should tell which plugin you use.

Comment: Try to make use of this part from the docs: **If the 'beforeSubmit' callback returns false then the form will not be submitted.** Or, you could try to employ jQuery's `.one()` method.

Comment: t.niese, I am using plugin jquery.form.min.js